# shuffling from an array with mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, random

I need some help here.

I have a mysql table called dictionary like this:

```
id  word
1 test
2 hello
4 bye
7 werd
```

In php, I want to query the db so that I can get an array of the id field

so the array would list 1 2 4 7.

With this array, I want to run the array_rand function in php so I can get a random number from 1 2 4 7.

Can someone show me the proper mysql query to list the id field and return it into php as an array?
and how I could run that array with random array function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need shuffle this in php, - effective is to

use  "SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY rand();"

than take all records and store id into array ...

Answer (score 1):

Use the [shuffle function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php)

Answer (score 0):

If you plan on using the random row and then querying for another, I would just randomize on the MySQL query.  Get a count of the rows in the table, create a random integer somewhere between 0 and that count, and then use LIMIT in your MySQL query to return a random row.

If you plan on keeping it all in memory, then David's answer would work better.